# Size of a {mxn} cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, size, cell-array

When I create a cell from a text file and print it I get:

params =

```
{4x1 cell}
```

However when I use:

size(X)

I get:

```
 1     1
```

So what can I use to see the size of the cell (I'm trying to get the size(in this case 4) of the cell to use in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be a 1x1 cell, then you can do

```
 size(X{1})
```

If not you could do

```
s = cellfun(@size, X, 'uni', 0);
s{:}
```